# How to rename multiple files in BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a list of files like this:

```
879061063811
879177411209
879177646578
879177927458
879177999903
879196145727
879272322985
879273522242
879273522946
879273527486
879279316113
879297532666
879373182204
879374889040
879378314075
879378411602
879603962878
879874713020
```

What do I need is an automatic BAT-file which will rename them into a list like this:

```
89061063811
89177411209
89177646578
89177927458
89177999903
89196145727
89272322985
89273522242
89273522946
89273527486
89279316113
89297532666
89373182204
89374889040
89378314075
89378411602
89603962878
89874713020
```

As you can see, all I want is get rid of second letter "7". I've cracked my head, then cracked the Google search for a very long time and didn't found the answer...

As I understand cmd doesn't have wildcards for first two letters, that's why I'm not restricting myself to using any cmd utilities. I know in Linux it could be much easier, but cmd is the only choice I have right now.

How would you solve this task?

Comment: Have you taken a look at PowerShell?

Comment: A quick-n-dirty solution: open Notepad++ (or any editor which supports column mode), and make the lines look line "ren 879061063811 89061063811". Save as .bat, and voila!

Comment: Kyle: I'll try to study PowerShell, but I'm not sure if it will help me

Comment: Paul: The problem is that I have too many patterns which has to be renamed, here's few of them: string >879
has to be replaced with >89

string >8+8
has to be replaced with  >89

string >889
has to be replaced with >89. And lists which has to be processed are too long to implement "ren *.* *.*" stuff you mention (Yes, I use Far Manager macroses in order to do that, but lists are too long even including that Far macroses are doing that)

Comment: Do the files have extensions, or are they literally numbers?

Comment: Files doesn't have extensions, they are literally numbers

Comment: Did any of these solutions help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /a-d 87*|sed -r "/^[0-9]7[0-9]+$/s/^(.)7(.*)/echo ren \"^&\" \"\1\2\"/e"
```

solution with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), remove `echo` to make it working.

Comment: This fails if 3rd character is 8 or 7. I know question source list does not, but I'm not sure that can be relied upon.

Comment: @dbenham I had another idea ... :)

Comment: You might want to modify the regex to ensure it only renames numeric file names.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the regex search string as needed to make sure only the correct files are renamed. FOR /F buffers the entire command output before iterating, unlike simple FOR, so it will never rename the same file twice.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd someDirectory
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d^| findstr /rx 87[0-9]*') do (
  set "name=%%a"
  ren "%%a" "!name:~0,1!!name:~2!"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=7" %%a in ('dir 87* /B /A-D') do ren %%a7%%b %%a%%b
```

For example:

```
> dir /b /a-d
879061063811
879177411209
879177646578
879177927458
879177999903
MyRen.bat

>MyRen.bat

>dir /b /a-d
89061063811
89177411209
89177646578
89177927458
89177999903
MyRen.bat
```

If you want to eliminate several different characters in second position, just assemble a list of they and use it at the rigth place. For example, to eliminate digits 0..7 in second position:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (0,1,7) do (
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=%%i" %%a in ('dir 8%%i* /B /A-D') do ren %%a%%i%%b %%a%%b
)
```

However, in this case you should use `move` instead of `ren` in order to move the renamed files out of the directory, so the next cycles don't rename they again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few simple steps to follow: -

Run CMD

Paste all txt files which do you want to rename on C:\

Type the rename command on CMD -   REN C:\89*.txt 87*.txt

I Hope this will solve your problem within a minute.